# Why are some AVRs marked with 'atmega' and some marked with 'mega'?

Tags: avr, atmel, reverse-engineering, hacking

I'm working on hacking the MCU in my MLP4DSM radio for an RC helicopter. The model number on the MCU is scratched out, but I can clearly read `MEGA` without an `AT` at the beginning. Google is letting me down. However, I can find AVRs marked either way scrolling through Google images. **Whats the difference?**

[image: ATmega328P-AU]
[image: Mega328P-AU]

Answer (score 2):

Differences between chips of the same model exist only when the revision changes, the logo doesn't play a part.

This is probably just a marketing decision like AVR studio toolchain that has been renamed to Atmel studio or the logo change from

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: Does that mean newer chips are marked 'mega' and older chips are marked 'atmega'? Getting an idea of the year this changed might help me narrow down the chips.

Comment: @OhmArchitect The logo change was in the middle of 2012 but I'm not sure how the logo  affected the markings on chips (if it did).

Comment: @OhmArchitect - The markings on the images you posted indicate that the chips were manufactured only one week apart - weeks 9 and 10 of 2007. It's hard to believe in such a coincidence. Another possibility is that one of them is a counterfeit (see [this question and answers](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/90692/29792)).

Comment: @Ricardo: I believe you have the date codes backwards.

Comment: @OhmArchitect [Date Code Management](http://www.atmel.com/about/quality/faq.aspx#body_12) `Atmel date codes are typically in the format "YYWW", whereby, "YY" corresponds to the last two digits of the year and "WW" indicates the workweek`. So the chips are 7th week of 2009 and 47th week of 2010

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Right! My mistake. The chips were manufactured almost 2 years apart.